# Head First JSP and Servlets book confusion

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I love Head First approach...
I have completed Head First Java and now I want to learn Java EE Technologies.. I would like to start by learning JSP and Servlets from "Head First Servlets & JSP"
But I do have access to only the previous edition written for 1.4 Exam...

Can I continue to learn with this book or do I have to start with the 2nd edition of this book written for Java 1.5

Is there any significant difference between the two editions?
After I complete learning from the book targeted for 1.4, would it no longer be used because of an enhanced functionality introduced with 1.5 !!!

I am not learning to take up any certification exam, trying to learn Java EE technologies...

Answer (score 2):

Java EE 5 and J2EE 1.4 are quite different standards, been Java EE 5 a radical improvement of the technlogy, as you can see [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_ee_5_vs_j2ee). It goes far beyond Servlets and JSP technologies and includes EJB 3, JPA, JAX-WS and other java standards.

But if you're only concerned in Web technologies, the changes are not that critical. Wikipedia says:

- Java Servlet specification goes from version 2.4 to 2.5
- JSP goes from version 2.0 to 2.1
- JSF and JSTL were included as standards

You can find the differences in the specifications [here](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/DifferenceBetweenServlet2.5AndServlet2.4.shtml). The changes are not that drastic so the knowledge you get from the book will be useful for Java EE 5 containers. Besides, the book is really great.

PS: I know you're not into certification, but if you're planing in getting certified the book works also for Java EE 5 exam.

Answer (score 0):

If you have studied Java 1.4, you will not have to worry, your programs will run on later versions of Java. This is called backward compatible. However, it is worth to explore innovations later version, because it increases your knowledge and ability. And though the old features will be supported, but they can be deprecated, and the use of such things is a bad practice.